# How much skin is a woman halachically allowed to show from the neck downward?

Tags: halacha, women, shiurim-measurements, parts-of-the-body

Is there a requirement to how much skin a woman can show - when going out in public - from where the neck ends to where the torso begins going downward at the top of her shirt?

The question is referring to figuring out what is considered "Ervah" in the area surrounding the neck.

Comment: highly related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4263/what-is-the-original-halachic-source-for-a-woman-covering-her-collarbones-out-of?rq=1

Comment: Is your question about the front, the back, or both?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the original halachic source for a woman covering her collarbones out of modesty (tznius)?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4263/what-is-the-original-halachic-source-for-a-woman-covering-her-collarbones-out-of)

Comment: @DonielF I disagree. This question asks "Is there a requirement," while the other asks for the earliest source of the requirement. They're definitely related, but I don't think they're duplicates.