# Source for tznius?

Tags: women, tznius-modesty

I am looking for information into the history of tznius in Jewish communities around the world. The main thing I'm interested is the differences in standards of modesty between different Jewish communities around the world and throughout history. How do the traditions of Sefardi, Mizrachi, Ashkenazi, Chassidic, etc differ regarding tznius laws and practices?  Thanks to all who replied to the original post and suggested I edit it!

Comment: You'll find that differences between Ashkenazi and Sephardi standards on tzinius are sometimes very great, especially when concerning Mizrahim.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya and thanks for a great "basics" question.

Comment: 'the modern standard of "knees, collarbones and elbows" become official' Who said it is official?

Comment: I think this may be a dupe of https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/55155/5275. The moderator put this on hold for a different reason. Check out the link, as it may be a dupe, anyway, Chaya. And the answers to most of your questions, may already be there.

Comment: Chaya Fischer, [welcome to Mi Yodeya](//judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887), and thanks very much for bringing your questions here! There's a lot going on here - too much to address in one Q&A post. Let's work together to [edit] this into something Mi Yodeya can handle. The first, most general, part, fleshed out just a little to indicate what you mean precisely by "tznius" in this case, could be a great question by itself. (1/2)

Comment: The second part has been posted [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4263/what-is-the-original-halachic-source-for-a-woman-covering-her-collarbones-out-of), so no need to make a separate post for that. The third part, about Sefaradic practice throughout history, feels like something that could be a book, but if you post that, again maybe with a little more detail or specifics, as a separate post, it might be possible to address it with a summary or link to a relevant book or other resource. (2/2)

Comment: Looking at the post @DanF found, I agree that that might cover your first part adequately. Take a look and see if it does, and what other questions it brings up. I'd encourage you to [edit] this post to either ask for something that's not yet covered there or to ask about the Sefaradi angle. (3/2)

Comment: @IsaacMoses I agree with everything you said except for your numbering system :-)